# Blue Prism - Namespace import

Tags: c#, namespaces, blueprism

I'm trying to use a Microsoft namespace, I need to enable the option "vote" of outlook, I'm doing it on the VBO - EmailPOP3/SMTP.

When I reference the namespace `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outook` on "Code options" the compiler show me the message:

```
Description: Compiler error at line 5135: 'Exception' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Exception' and 'System.Exception'
```

But, Idk how I can give an "alias" to namespace or another solution for this issue.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Formatting and grammar

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way in Blue Prism to set a namespace alias.

If you have any references to Exception in your code, try explicitly referring to System.Exception instead. I just tried it on a block of code, and the compiler error went away after I made the explicit reference to System.Exception.